# Get a List of objects, inside another list of objects in lamba expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following classes:

```
public class ClassA(){
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ClassB> ClassBs{ get; set; }
}

public class ClassB(){
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ClassAId{ get; set; }
    public int ClassCId{ get; set; }

    public virtual ClassA ClassA{ get; set; }
    public virtual ClassC ClassC{ get; set; }
}

public class ClassC(){
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public ICollection<ClassB> ClassBs{ get; set; }
}
```

Now, I have a list of ClassC objects, that comes from the user`s selection.

Let's say the user chose the ClassC's of Ids 1 and 3. I need to return a list of all ClassA objects meets the criteria.

Comment: so you need the ClassA objects inside ClassC's list of ClassB objects where ClassB.ClassAID = 1 or 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A general rule for situations when you have a collection of collections, and you wish to return elements of the collection on the inside, is to use `SelectMany` before doing further processing. In your case this would look as follows:

```
var res = collectionOfCs
    .Where(cItem => ... /* Condition on ClassC */)
    .SelectMany(cItem => cItem.ClassBs.Select(bItem => bItem.ClassA)) 
    .Where(aItem => ... /* Condition on ClassA */)
```

You could separate selection of `ClassA`s from `SelectMany`, but the overall structure of the query would remain the same:

```
var res = collectionOfCs
    .Where(cItem => ... /* Condition on ClassC */)
    .SelectMany(cItem => cItem.ClassBs)
    .Select(bItem => bItem.ClassA) // Moved from SelectMany
    .Where(aItem => ... /* Condition on ClassA */)
```

Comment: what is the difference between Select and SelectMany? I've never used SelectMany and from your example it looks to me like Select would perform the same way so I'm wondering what I'm not understanding

Comment: @MarcoFatica `SelectMany` is for flattening collections of collections. Let's say you have an array of arrays like this: `[[1,2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]`. If you use `Select` on it, you would get an `IEnumerable<int[]>` with three elements representing the individual arrays. If you do `SelectMany` you would get an `IEnumerable<int>` with seven elements representing the individual integers.

Comment: oh okay i get it now. so if you just used `Select(cItem => cItem.ClassBs)` your next select would have to be `Select(bList => bList.Where(bItem => bItem.ClassA))` correct? because instead of flattening all the ClassBs into a single enumerator with `SelectMany`, you're `Select`ing from an enumerator of enumerators for the second select?

Comment: @MarcoFatica That's correct. You would also get an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<ClassB>>` as the result, not an `IEnumerable<ClassA>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @dasblinkenlight. Another way I found out was using LINQ.    `return (from item in listOfBs where item.ClassAId== id select item.ClassC).ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SelectMany` extension method:

```
var query = listOfClassC.Where(c => c.Id == 1 || c.Id == 3)
                        .SelectMany(c => c.ClassBs.Select(b => b.ClassA));
```

Now, to filter better the objects of type `ClassC`, you can also do this using the `Contains` method:

```
var ClassCIds=new List<int>(){1,3}; // Add here the ids what you want to filter
var query = listOfClassC.Where(c => ClassCIds.Contains(c.Id))
                        .SelectMany(c => c.ClassBs.Select(b => b.ClassA));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listOfObjectsOfClassA.Where(a => a.ClassBs
    .Where(b => listOfUserProvidedIds.Contains(b.ClassCId))
.Count() > 0)
.ToList()
```

That should do what you're asking for, unless I've missunderstood something.

What that does is, take the list of `ClassA` objects, goes through the `ClassB` list that is inside every `ClassA` object and checks if the list of user provided IDs (in your example that list would contain `1`and `3`) contains the `ClassCId` that is assigned to the specific `ClassB` object.